# Django ImageField: directly using file from disk

Tags: python, django, file, filefield

I have a file on my disk, say:

`/home/user/file.png`

And I have a model with a `StdImageField` (which is similar to the ImageField, just some additional options), [more here](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage).

**models.py:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = StdImageField(upload_to="images", variations={"thumbnail": (600,400), "normal": (1000, 600)}, blank=True, null=True)
```

What I'd like to do is programatically "upload" this image. I do **not** just want to assign the existing path to the field, as I want the image to be stored in the right folder and properly resized.

So let's say I have an instance of my model in the variable `obj`, then I'm trying to do the following:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
open_file = open("/home/user/file.png", "rb")
django_file = ImageFile(open_file)
obj.image = django_file
obj.save()
```

Now at first sight this works well because a) my image gets moved to the right folder `images` in my media root, and b) the image gets resized properly. However, after this operation the database field with the path to the file turns absolute, containing the entire path to the media root:

`/src/media/images/file.png`

But this is not how it normally works -- this is supposed to be relative and only contain:

`images/file.png`

Why does it become an absolute field and how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**`uploadedfile`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) class as

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile

instance = MyModel(
    image=UploadedFile(
        file=open("/home/user/path/to/file/foo.jpg", 'rb')
    )
)
instance.save()
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Great, that works! I can only accept in 9h but this solves it!